# JSF external file based on locale

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have an JSF application where I want to send an email from. Now I don't want to put the email's content in my i18n file. I thought to save it in an external file, lets say `email1_de.txt` and `email1_en.txt`.

Can I somehow load this file depending on the user's locale?

Thanks

Comment: How external is "external"? Is it available via classpath? Or could its path be added to the classpath? If so, `ResourceBundle` would be easy.

Comment: Yes it would be accessible via classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a resource bundle.
1. Create a Message.properties file in one of your source code packages and then in that file, add your email content, in plain or HTML format as follows:

```
message.test3 = This is "<h2>message.test4</h2>"
message.param1 = This is "message.param1" - {0}
message.param2 = This is "message.param2" - {0} and {1}
```

You may even include parameters.

2. Declare your resource bundle in your faces-config.xml file
3. You can call the text in your resource bundle from you class or from your HTML files.

You may look at this example: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-and-resource-bundles-example/

If you are dealing with different locales, then you can look here: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-internationalization-example/

It is explained pretty well.